# Application stopped responding

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

My windows application entry point is Main form constructor. When the application starts it start a thread, which is kept running. After few days my application crashes giving the popup of application stopped working.

```
public MDIForm()
{            
InitializeComponent();
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
{
    Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    logtofile"MDIForm; Error; UnhandledException;" + ex.Message);
    logtofile("MDIForm" + " StackTrace: UnhandledException: '{0}'" + Environment.StackTrace);
};
Application.ThreadException += (s, ex) =>
{
    Exception exc = (Exception)ex.Exception;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
    logtofile("MDIForm; Error; ThreadException; " + exc.Message);
    logtofile("MDIForm" + " StackTrace: ThreadException: '{0}'" + Environment.StackTrace);
};
}
```

Following function is called from thread at startup of the application.

```
private void MyFunction_RunThread()
{
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        //My Code
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    //My Code
}
}
```

After adding the code for Stacetrace, following reference log is captured.

```
MDIForm StackTrace: UnhandledException: '{0}'   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at MyApp.MDIForm.<.ctor>b__0(Object s, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntCreateWindowEx(Int32 dwExStyle, String lpszClassName, String lpszWindowName, Int32 style, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, HandleRef hWndParent, HandleRef hMenu, HandleRef hInst, Object pvParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(Int32 dwExStyle, String lpszClassName, String lpszWindowName, Int32 style, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, HandleRef hWndParent, HandleRef hMenu, HandleRef hInst, Object pvParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.MarshalingControl..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.get_MarshalingControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
   at MyApp.MyClass.MyFunction_RunThread()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuQPv.png)

Comment: you should look into asynchronous programming (but this would not fix your issue I guess)

Comment: I don't see the exception message, only the stacktrace. Also, while we know that it wasn't handled, we also don't know the type of the exception. Do you have that information. (If not you may need to run it for a few days again.)

Comment: Thanks, Denis and Scott

Comment: Application based on tcp communication. Which has a thread MyFunction_RunThread(), it starts after communication is established. This app crashes abruptly

Comment: application crash image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuQPv.png)